# Error in React Native with RealmJS- Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: react-native, realm-js

> Using Node.js v12.13.0 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ABC/Projects/ReactNative/Project ABCD'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
>       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: `/Users/ABC/Projects/ReactNative/ABCD` is this module available?

Comment: this is project directory. ABCD is project name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to reference a module that lives somewhere else. Can we see project code and file structure?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by just removing a space from project folder name.

'Project ABCD' -> 'Project_ABCD'